# How to release variable in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Under automatic reference counting, why are retain, release, and dealloc not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273341/under-automatic-reference-counting-why-are-retain-release-and-dealloc-not-all)

I want to release variable in xcode 4.2. When i am releasing it throws me an error.
The error is Automatic reference counting forbids explicit message send of 'release'

Edited:

Below marked answer worked for me and also I couldn't realize that this question has been asked. Anyways happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have ARC enabled (Automatic Reference Counting).  You can either disable this new feature or learn how to use it.  To disable it, click on your project -> your current app target -> Build Settings -> Set Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting to NO.

To learn more about this, you can look at Apple's documentation for [Transitioning to ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html).