# ARC forbids explicit message send of release. Request for suggestion concerning error and statement tags

Tags: ios4, xcode4.3

Does any one have any suggestion on alternative code to use instead of [view release]; (see below code snippet).
Any ideas on for a solution or any comments would be most appreciative.

Alos Iv included an code snippet with a yellow comment tag. anybody got any suggestions again would be much appreciated.

I am rebuilding  in Xcode 4.3 the app I built in an earlier version of xcode to be compatible with the new image requirements  etc.

[code snippet http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/3267/20120712121243pm.png](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/3267/20120712121243pm.png)
[code snippet2 http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/6616/hfile.png](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/6616/hfile.png)

Comment: Refer this SOF question. This may give you some idea about what happens when using ARC.


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273341/under-automatic-reference-counting-why-are-retain-release-and-dealloc-not-all